# How to remove "Unable to merge android manifest" error in unity-5

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, android-manifest

I am beginner to Unity and am trying to integrate Admob to my unity project. The problem is it gives error saying

> Unable to merge Android manifests, see the console for more details, see the console for details

i have applied all the solutions like

- changing the minSDKversion
- changing the targetSDKversion
- Deleting manifests
- many more

but still got stuck with the bug.

Here is the error.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="D:/Android SDK installer\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Unity 5.6.1 Install\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, D:\HR-PTech\Admob Test App\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-11.0.2\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element:
  <activity
--    @android:exported="false"
--    @android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
--    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
  <activity
++    @android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
++    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
++</activity>
]
stdout[
Warning: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:2, D:\HR-PTech\Admob Test App\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.runtime-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion='25'> but library uses targetSdkVersion='26'
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, D:\HorseRacing-PureTechGame\Admob Test App\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-compat-26.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=android.support.VERSION] element.
```

Comment: `Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion='25'> but library uses targetSdkVersion='26'` so did you try to set the main manifest's `targetSdkVersion` to `26`?

Comment: yes i did @derHugo